# Need help numbering rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm working with t-sql and I need to order a result set in a custom manner. Consider the following table and query:

```
CREATE TABLE DeleteMe
(Col1 INT)

INSERT INTO DeleteMe
VALUES
(0), (2), (2), (3), (4), (4), (4)

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1) AS OrderBy, Col1 FROM DeleteMe
ORDER BY Col1
```

Returning:

OrderBy Col1

1   0

2   2

3   2

4   3

5   4

6   4

7   4

However, what I need is this:

OrderBy Col1

1   0

2   2

2   2

3   3

4   4

4   4

4   4

Essentially, for each value of Col1 that is the same, the OrderBy value should be the same. The OrderBy attribute needs to start at 1 and be sequential. So if you deleted the record where Col1 = 0, the result would again start at 1:

OrderBy Col1

1   2

1   2

2   3

3   4

3   4

3   4

I've been playing with Partition By and some other things and I'm stumped at this point. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: row_number() cannot/will not return a repeated number within a partition, so dense_rank() is the better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Dense_Rank:

```
SELECT dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY Col1) AS OrderBy, Col1 FROM DeleteMe
ORDER BY Col1
```

Comment: Wasn't aware of dense_rank(), works like a charm. Many thanks.

Comment: There are four "ranking functions" in SQL Server. Row_number is the most useful, but the others are well worth being aware of.